# curl_init() not working when php script accessed from browser

Tags: apache2, php

Ubuntu 16.04.1, Apache2 server.

Simple PHP script:  `index.php`

```
<?php
    echo "A";
    $ch = curl_init();
    echo "B";
```

The output should be: `AB` , works fine from the terminal.

Yet, when I open `index.php` from the browser the output is: `A`

Apparently, an error occurs... but the script stopped when it reaches `curl_init()`.

1. `try-catch` block doesn't catch the error.
2. The `curl_error($ch)` doesn't help since that line never reached.

To eliminate the permissions reason,
I also tried to run the script from terminal using `www-data` user, working fine.

From Apache2 `error.log`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
in /var/www/html/index.php:4\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in
/var/www/html/index.php on line 4
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install `php-curl` package, depending of your PHP version. If this is the default version for Ubuntu 16.04 - `php7.0`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.0-curl
sudo phpenmod curl
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```